# Form Error in zend framework 2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend Framework 2. I am getting a fatal error message when I am creating a form.

This is my form class:

```
namespace Myform\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class CustomerloginForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name); 

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'BusEnquiry',
                'id' => 'btn-fblogin',
                'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                'style'=>'float:left;position:relative;left:5px;'    
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

This is my controller class:

```
namespace Myform\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

use Myform\Form\CustomerloginForm;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{   
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = new CustomerloginForm('customerloginForm');  
        //this is the problem area 
        //I am getting a fatal error message that CustomerloginForm class can not be found
        return new viewModel(); 
     }
}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Myform\Form\CustomerloginForm' not found

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should check:

- Is your file name corresponding to your class name?
  So the file name should be `CustomerloginForm.php` (watch the capitalization).
- Is the class `CustomerloginForm` in the correct namespace? 
  (should be: `...\src\Myform\Form\CustomerloginForm.php`)
- Is your folder structure correct? The problem might be related to some autoloading problem.

Comment: thnx to reply  i solved problem    u r right my folder name was wrong thnx  love you stackoverflow  and all members

Comment: @PRASHANTMAROTHIYA If my answer solved your issue it would be great if you can accept it. Then others also know that the question is answered.